# After adding switch to network, Windows shares no longer accessible on OS X

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, osx-leopard

This has been bugging me a lot today:

I have several computers behind a router. 
One of them serves Windows shares and is connected to the router by ethernet cable. 
The main client is connected to the router by Wi-Fi, and could connect to the shares just fine. 
But today I added a switch to the mix, so that the server is now connected to the switch, which in turn is connected to the router.
**Poof**, the wireless client can no longer connect to the server's shares. It can still ping it, attach a remote desktop session, etc., but network shares are not working.

Server is Windows 7, client Mac OS 10.5.

What could be going on here?

So far I've rebooted router, server, client and even switch. No help.

**Edit**: Turns out other clients, and even the same MacBook Pro, can access the shares just fine if/when running Windows as opposed to Mac OS X. My Linux based smartphone connects just fine too.

Comment: So it only has this problem when running OSX on the Mac? If you pop the switch back out of the equation does OSX start working as expected?  What kind (make/model) of switch is it?

Comment: Indeed so. The switch is a [D-Link DGS-1008D](http://www.dlink.ca/products/?pid=230).

Comment: This Mac, whether running Windows or OSX, both use the same network card, correct?  Want to try and eliminate ARP cache from the equation

Comment: Hmm, arp should remain the same if this is a switch.  My guess would be that the link speed autonegotiate is failing, and some packet loss is occurring.  Does OSX and Windows connect at the same speed (you should be able to tell from the LED)

Comment: I'll check. Another hypothesis is that another computer (the reason I installed the switch in the first place) is causing the problem. Will post back later today. @Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a fluke, as a **cold** reboot (of the Mac) appears to have resolved the problem.